# Least trimmed squares vs. OLS with omitted observations

Tags: regression, outliers, robust

I'm trying to understand the output generated from a least trimmed squares regression. As far as I understand, least trimmed squarres performs basic OLS, then you order the residuals and only include the observations with the k-smallest residuals in another OLS regression, which is then your least trimmed squares estimator. 
I've been trying to implement this in R, meaning I performed OLS regression (green line), then searched for the biggest residual, excluded that from my data and ran the OLS again (blue line) but it doesn't give me the same output as the least trimmed squares estimator (red line).
Do I have any error in my reasoning?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: I have the same problem with ltsReg from the robustbase package (see below for an example)
[image]

Image is made with the following R code:

```
### Example
library(MASS)
y = c(0,0,0,2,3, 0, 0)
x = 1:7
plot(x,y)
reg = lm(y ~ x+ 0)
abline(reg,col ='green')
reg_lts <- ltsreg(x, y, intercept = FALSE, quantile = 6)
abline(reg_lts,col ='red')
A = cbind(x,y,reg$residuals)
## Remove observation with highest residual
y = y[-5]
x = x[-5]
reg2 = lm(y ~ x+ 0)
abline(reg2,col ='blue')
```

Example with ltsReg

[image]

```
libary(robustbase)
x = c(-81,  -16 , -70 , -95,  -64 ,  84 ,  -3,   17,  -15 , -34 , -42,   17 , -23, -170, -117,  -63, -120,  -14,    0,  -34,  -12 , 107,-7,  -59 ,  59,   17,  170,  -64,  -96,  -60 , -84,   27 ,  66 ,  63,   55 ,  37 ,  11  ,-15)
y = c( -54,  -12,    0,  -24 , -66,    0 , -60,    6,    0  ,  0 , -24  ,  6,    0, -126  ,  6,    0 , -78 , -12,    0,    0 , -36,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    6,    0,    6,   12,   -6,    0,   42,    6,    6)
plot(x,y)
reg = lm(y ~ x+ 0)
abline(reg,col ='green')
reg_lts <- ltsReg(y~0+x, alpha = 0.95)
abline(reg_lts,col ='red')
A = cbind(x,y,reg$residuals)
## Remove the two observation with highest residuals, two since floor(38*0.95) = 36
y = y[c(-7,-14)]
x = x[c(-7,-14)]
reg2 = lm(y ~ x+ 0)
abline(reg2,col ='blue')
```

Comment: I have compared your results with those using `ltsReg` from the `robustbase` package: `reg_lts <- ltsReg(y~x+0, alpha=0.85)`, and using `ltsReg` gives exactly the same results as your `reg2` generates (which is what you want.)  I suspect the MASS implementation uses a robust estimate of scale even for lts, based on this unclear line from the documentation w.r.t. the definition of "scale": "The second (not present for method == "S") is based on the variance of those residuals whose absolute value is less than 2.5 times the initial estimate."  That may filter out the second-largest error.

Comment: That sounds like it could be the reason. Nonetheless, ltsReg must have something similar, since I have the same problem with a slightly different dataset. I updated the question and added another example. Do you know what could be the reason for that in ltsReg?

Comment: `ltsReg` does work as designed.  First, try setting your alpha to 0.94444, this will remove (almost) exactly two observations.  If you put in 0.95, the obs. with the second-largest squared residual gets a fractional weight (20% of a full observation, given that your sample size is 36 and 0.95*36 = 34.2.)  Second, look at the residuals from `reg_lts`; you will see the largest two (in absolute value) are actually numbers 5 and 7, not 7 and 14.  If you then remove observations 5 and 7 and run the `lm`, the lines basically overlap.